# How to embed a video in an Alfresco blog / wiki?

Tags: video, embed, alfresco

I just don't know how....

All 'embed' and such tags are removed.

I'd like a simple clean solution .

Allowing all code is not option (modyfing wiki.get.config.xml)

Thanks a lot !!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is not a very elegant solution, but I guess you could embed an image (a snapshot of your video), and link it to the actual video in the document library.